# Why isn't my assignment operator getting called?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I'm confused... why isn't my assignment operator getting called here?

```
template<typename This>
struct mybase
{
    This& operator =(const This &other)
    {
        __debugbreak();  // The debugger should break here, but doesn't.
        return static_cast<This &>(*this):
    }
};

struct myderived : mybase<myderived>
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    myderived a = myderived();  // And yes, I know it's redundant...
    myderived b = myderived();
    a = b;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mybase::operator=` is *hidden* by the automatically generated copy assignment operator `myderived::operator=`.

You can use a `using` declaration to make the base class operator visible in the derived class.

**EDIT:** added example per request:

```
template<typename This>
struct mybase
{
    This& operator =(const This &other)
    {
        //__debugbreak();  // The debugger should break here, but doesn't.
        return static_cast<This &>(*this);
    }
};

struct myderived : mybase<myderived>
{
    using mybase<myderived>::operator=;
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    myderived a = myderived();  // And yes, I know it's redundant...
    myderived b = myderived();
    a = b;
}
```

This compiles fine with Visual C++ 10.0 and with Comeau Online. The latter means, in practice, that it's good standard C++. However, the code does not compile with MinGW g++ 4.4.1 (compiler bug).

**EDIT 2:** Actually, checking now, with Visual C++ 10.0 it compiles but the base class operator is not invoked. So maybe g++ is correct. `using` is generally the way to bring in a base class assignment operator (or whatever), but in this case it has the same signature as the derived class’ copy assignment operator, and I do not yet know whether Visual C++ behavior is correct or not  –  it is a corner case of the language.

**EDIT 3:** I checked N3290 (the standard draft that is identical to C++11), and it says

> **§12.8/18:**
>   If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4).

I personally interpret that as saying that with the `using` declaration in place the class “declares” a copy assignment operator, and that one should therefore not be implicitly generated (as it seems that Visual C++ 10.0 does). However, this is a corner case of the language. Others may possibly interpret this differently, and as noted above, compilers differ!

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Whoa really? That would be awesome; could you please provide an example of how to use `using`?

Comment: clang++ 3.0 on cygwin generates the following: `error: use of overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous (with operand types 'myderived' and 'myderived')`. So we basically get 2 compile errors, 1 base class and 1 derived class call. Ie maybe there is one correct interpretation of the standard in that situation, but nobody seems to agree what it is ;)

Answer (score 6):

Because the default assignment operator in derived will hide the overloaded in base.

Comment: Wait really?? Is there a way to avoid this, while keeping the assignment operator in the base class?

Comment: @Mehrdad: `using base::operator=`

Comment: @Tony: But that means I still have to override it manually in every class... which is what I'm trying to avoid. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
a = b;
```

obviously requires that `myderived` have overloaded the copy assignment operator. It can be implicitly generated by the compiler, or defined by the `myderived` class explicitly:

> **12.8 Copying class objects [class.copy]**
>
> *9.* A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a
>   non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one
>   parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const
>   volatile X&`.

You have attempted to create a user-declared copy assignment operator in your `mybase` class, but it's not actually a copy assignment operator according to the C++ standard. Imagine if we did a type substitution for `This` with `myderived`:

```
// Hypothetical class generated by the compiler from
// the mybase template class with This = myderived
struct mybase_myderived 
{
    myderived& operator =(const myderived &other) 
    { 
        // ...
    } 
};
```

Clearly that's not a copy assignment operator, because the parameter `other` is of type `const myderived&`, not `const mybase&`. Had the `other` parameter be of type `const mybase&`, or `mybase`, or `mybase&`, then it would be a valid copy assignment operator, which can be called by the default copy assignment operator in `myderived`. But it isn't in this case, so the compiler still generates a default copy assignment operator for `mybase`, which of course does nothing in this case.

The compiler-generated default copy assignment operator in `myderived` calls the compiler-generated default copy assignment operator in `mybase`. So what ends up happening, as As a result, the `operator=(const myderived &other)` overload is never called.

The reason why the compiler doesn't just call `mybase::operator=` directly is because it's been hidden by the compiler-generated copy assignment operator in `myderived`, as Alf P. Steinbach points out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380450/why-isnt-my-assignment-operator-getting-called/7380491#7380491).

Comment: Huh? What's a "copy-assignment operator"?

Comment: I don't understand how this is *not* a copy-assignment operator...  according to your link it has to be: *The copy assignment operator [...] is a special case of assignment operator where the source (right-hand side) and destination (left-hand side) are of the same class type.*

Comment: @Mehrdad: The RHS is `This`. The LHS is `mybase<This>`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Wait, why? So the compiler auto-casts to the base class before calling the method?

Comment: @Mehrdad: C++ standard 12.8/9 says: "A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`". So it's not a copy-assignment operator unless `X` is the same type as the class for which it is a member of.

Comment: @Mehrdad: a copy assignment operator for a class `T` accepts actual argument of type `T`. It is not formally required to return `T&`. For example, personally I find it mainly irrelevant to chain assignments, and I think it's bad practice, so I would like to see more `void` result assignment operators... ;-)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Huh? This is an `operator=` in class `mybase<This>` that takes a `const This&` instead of a `const mybase<This>&`. Simples!

Comment: @Tomalak: Okay thanks. :) For some reason I expected this to behave like some sort of mixin, but apparently it doesn't quite do that.

Comment: @Alf: Usually when programmers overload operators they make it so that it behaves as though the class type was a primitive type. For example, I can do this: `int x; int y; int z; x = y = z = 0`. Making the copy assignment operator return `void` would making something like `MyClass x, y, z; x = y = z;` invalid.

Comment: @Tomalak: no. think about it. all that effort to support assignment chaining, and how much is it used? about not at all. and where it's used, i suspect bugs lurking. best not. :-)

Comment: @Alf: You're going to deliberately introduce into the world copy assignment operators that return `void`? Please don't?

Comment: @Alf: And `return *this;` takes "all that effort" to write in order to support chaining?

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler introduces the default assignment operator in myderived. Override it and call your base assignment operator yourself. Or perhaps a using directive will help? Try using mybase::operator= in myderived body.